# iPhone SDK: How do I programmatically create squares?

Tags: iphone, drawing, rendering

Does anyone know how I can programmatically create a grid of squares. (each square being 10x10) ?

What i'd like to do is to simulate a digital display, so I would need to be able to set the colour of each individual square, after its been defined as well.

I know I could make each individual square in interface builder, but that would be simply impractical with all the required outlets.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to create your own [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) class that implemented the necessary abstractions and carried out the relevant drawing within its drawRect method.

Have you looked at the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066) or [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)? These will provide the necessary background information on the various primative drawing operations and should at least point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom view, override `drawRect`: and call `UIRectFill` to draw squares.

[See this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-BBCHFJJG)

Comment: NSRectFill is actually from AppKit (Mac only), you have to use UIRectFill on iPhone (or Core Graphics directly).

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the Apple sample project for example of drawing (square, circles, elipse, etc)

[QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuartzDemo/QuartzDemo.zip)

Hope this helps.